# passing parameters to weblogic silent installation file

Tags: xml, unix, weblogic

I am trying to install weblogic server(10.3.6) using silent mode by passing parameters dynamically in my linux machine using bash shell.

Below is my silent XML file:

```
<bea-installer> 
    <input-fields>
        <data-value name="BEAHOME" value="$MID_HOME" />
        <data-value name="WLS_INSTALL_DIR" value="$MID_HOME"/wlserver_10.3 />
        <data-value name="COMPONENT_PATHS" value="WebLogic Server/Core Application Server|WebLogic Server/Administration Console|WebLogic Server/Configuration Wizard and Upgrade Framework" />
        <data-value name="INSTALL_NODE_MANAGER_SERVICE" value="no" />
    </input-fields> 
</bea-installer>
```

I am using below command to install:

```
java -jar wls1036_generic.jar -mode=silent -silent_xml=silent.xml
```

But I am getting error as :

```
Extracting 0%....................................................................................................100%
The directory path must be absolute: [$MID_HOME]
```

But I have defined the variable `MID_HOME as /scratch/user1/weblogic/Middleware`, also if I give complete path in my silent.xml file instead of using parameters($MID_HOME) then it is working fine.

Please help me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when the XML file is parsed, there is no expansion happening for `$MID_HOME` (XML parsers are not shells, so some other processing would have to expand `$MID_HOME`).

What happens when you change the XML file to contain

```
value="/scratch/user1/weblogic/Middleware"
```

in the appropriate tags?

And this

```
value="$MID_HOME"/wlserver_10.3
```

isn't valid XML; attributes values must have their end quote at the end.

Comment: Hi Jean, It is working if I give full path instead of using parameters.

Comment: Okay, then it looks like the installation process doesn't support shell variable references in XML attribute values. If you think my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting this answer.

Comment: Thanks Jens for for the answer